# Fastest way to reverse the order of a PriorityQueue in Java

Tags: java, queue

In my implementation, I am adding objects to a PriorityQueue based on the value of a parameter `a` that they have. Simply said, I am adding elements to the PriorityQueue such that the elements with the largest value are in front of the queue by using the `Comparator.comparingDouble(Object -> -Object.a)`. Whenever the size of the queue is larger than a predefined threshold, I poll an element for the queue. In this way, the queue will contain the elements with the most negative value.

In the next part of my code, I want to consider the elements in the queue in increasing order of the value of `a`, thus the reverse of the queue I am currently having.

What is the fastest way to do this/what other options for the first part do I have?

In the following, I worked out a small example to illustrate what I want to have. Suppose I have a list with five elements [4,2,7,9,1] and I want to keep the three smallest one. 
The Priorityqueue will then equal:

- [4]
- [4,2]
- [7,4,2]
- [9,7,4,2] -> [7,4,2] after poll()
- [7,4,2,1] -> [4,2,1] after poll()

For my next part of the code I would like to iterate over the reverse of this queue: [1,2,4].

Note that this example is rather easy and simple, but that in my code the list can easily contain more than 1,000,000 elements.

I am open for all suggestions!

Comment: Create a new `PriorityQueue` with a negated comparator, and add all the items from the existing `PriorityQueue` to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

`PriorityQueue` is implemented as a heap data structure; as such, its elements are not really ordered. Finding the largest element in a heap is `O(1)`, but finding the smallest is `O(n)`. You won't be able to easily obtain a reversed view from the data structure itself.

So, the answer to your question will be expensive computationally:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue;
// this step will be expensive ~ n log(n)
List<Integer> values = queue.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
// this also won't be cheap ~ n
Collections.reverse(values);
```

Depending on your usage patterns, you may want to opt for a data structure that might be more expensive to add to and remove from, but is cheaper to reverse. `TreeSet` comes to mind with its `.iterator()` and `.descendingIterator()` methods.

Comment: The elements *are* ordered; they're in heap order. They're just not *sorted*.